# Unlocking a read lock set while iterating task list before doing a sleepy operation on kernel

Tags: process, linux-kernel, driver

From my kernel module I want to iterate over task list and do some sleepy operation for all the processes for which my task->flag is set. I know by holding read_lock(tasklist_lock)/rcu_read_lock, I should not be doing any sleepy operation. SO I have coded like below :

1.Take the read lock
2.Iterate over task (for_each_process)
3.If my flag  is set I unlock the tasklist_lock and get_task_struct
4.Then I perform the sleepy operation
5.Put_task_struct
6.Again Take read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
7.Loop continues

```
read_lock(&tasklist_lock);

    for_each_process(c) {

            if (c->my_flag) {

            read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);

                    get_task_struct(c);

                         ...

                         Do some sleepy_operation()

                         ...

                    put_task_struct(c);

                    read_lock(&tasklist_lock);

            }
    }
```

Please let me know if my approach is correct